# How to remove outline on QToolButton

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm developing Qt application for Mac OS X.
Problem is when I create QToolButton it apears with some outline.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqtP9.png

I use next stylesheet

```
QToolButton {  
    border: 1px solid #575757;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

How to remove the outline?

---

ANSWER:

I didn't mentioned that I'm adding this item to statusBar().

To remove border around the item I used:

```
QStatusBar::item {border: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
QToolButton {  
    border: 1px solid #575757;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: palette(base);
}
```

Usually, web best-practices recommand that if you change one color, you have to change them all.

It is likely that you will also have to change the text color as well to avoid potential issues on some computers with non-default window text color.

Comment: Yes I tried it but it only change color inside the button, not the outline :(

Comment: @Aleksandar: I admit this is weird. What happens if you change the background-color of the first parent ? Does it change the color of the outline ?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

> yourWidgetElement->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus ) ;